# Macbook pro 13" early 2015 freezes and shut down

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

Macbook pro 13" early 2015 freezing after login.

**Tried solutions**

- Format and Reinstall OS
- Apple Hardware diagnose
- SMC and PRAM reset
- Open in safe mode
- Stopped using google chrome
- Disabled Firevault

However, sometimes after trying for 2-3 days it suddenly starts working then again a few days later it back to freeze and shut down.

**System Specs**

- 8 GB ram
- 512 SSD
- 2.9 GHz
- Dual core i5

Comment: "Format and reinstall" was that a full recovery of everything you had before, or did you test out before recovering?

Comment: Assuming that you did as @Allan suggested and used the Mac *before* you went and restored your apps and data and the problem still occurs it sounds like an intermittent hardware issue. RAM, battery, system board, GPU, etc. Which are *very* tough to diagnose due to their unpredictability. But a qualified Apple certified tech (Apple store or authorized Apple dealer) should be able to nail it down if they can have the Mac for long enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took it to the repair center and it was a hardware issue with one of the chips. They replaced it and now my MBP is back into action.